# Force use HTTPS with .COM domain and WWW in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a permanent redirect 301 to all the traffic to a main .com domain.
I have 3 domains:

```
example.com -> Main Domain
example.net
example.org
```

Rules are:

- Always use https (http -> https)
- Use only .com Domain (.org|.net|AnyOther -> .com)
- Force www Only for root domains *Exclude subdomains (non-www -> wwww)

Example:

```
http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
http://example.net -> https://www.example.com
http://example.org -> https://www.example.com

https://example.com -> https://www.example.com
https://example.net -> https://www.example.com
https://example.org -> https://www.example.com

http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com
http://www.example.net -> https://www.example.com
http://www.example.org -> https://www.example.com

https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com -> OK
https://www.example.net -> https://www.example.com
https://www.example.org -> https://www.example.com

http://example.com/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder
http://example.net/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder
http://example.org/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder

https://example.com/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder
https://example.net/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder
https://example.org/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder

http://www.example.com/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder
http://www.example.net/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder
http://www.example.org/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder

https://www.example.com/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder -> OK
https://www.example.net/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder
https://www.example.org/subfolder -> https://www.example.com/subfolder

http://client1.example.com -> https://client1.example.com
http://client1.example.net -> https://client1.example.com
http://client1.example.org -> https://client1.example.com

https://client1.example.com -> https://client1.example.com -> OK
https://client1.example.net -> https://client1.example.com
https://client1.example.org -> https://client1.example.com

http://client1.example.com/subfolder -> https://client1.example.com/subfolder
http://client1.example.net/subfolder -> https://client1.example.com/subfolder
http://client1.example.org/subfolder -> https://client1.example.com/subfolder

https://client1.example.com/subfolder -> https://client1.example.com/subfolder -> OK
https://client1.example.net/subfolder -> https://client1.example.com/subfolder
https://client1.example.org/subfolder -> https://client1.example.com/subfolder
```

**UPDATE**

Usually I use this code that I made in htaccess but the problem is that it adds www to the subdomains.

```
# Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Force .com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please add your own current attempt to implement this. There are literally hundreds of answers for this alone here on SO. So you already have all the information you need. If that did not help, surprisingly, then you need to tell us what exactly you tried and what detail did not work as desired. Without that there is little we can help to fix that issue. _Please note that we are not a free coding service_ , so we are not here to do your work for you. You are actually expected to do that yourself. We are here to help and provide answers to _specific_ questions.

Comment: Hello @arkascha 
I'm sorry it was my fault I didn't add the code. Please see my update to the code I have currently tried Regards

Answer (score 0):

Finally after continuous search and investigation I have managed to modify the code to make it work correctly, I hope it will help someone else.

Working .htaccess

```
# Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^websuiter\.(net|org|com)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force .com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?+(.+?)\.(?!com$)[^.]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1.com/$0 [R=301,NE,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Great you found a solution. One obvious improvement to the first rule would be to immediately set the `.com` TLD here, that saves a second immediate redirection by the second rule. But that is just a detail.